# calling webservice from javascript and wait for response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, intervals

I have created a webservice and want to call it from javascript , for this I have registered ServiceReference in my page's script manager, and called webservice using namespace.

My problem is that I want to wait until response from webservice received.

For this I was trying to using setInterval but that does not work.

Any other way to achieve this?

More Details are below:
In Javascript If you write a function to call WebService you have to pass it a method signature that will be called after webservice sends response.

e.g.

```
var IsResponseReceived;
function GetSomethingFromWebService()
{
  IsResponseReceived = 'No';
  Namespace.WebServiceClass.GetMeSomething(parameter1,SuccessResponseReceiver);
  alert(webServiceResponse);
}

function SuccessResponseReceiver(parameter1,parameter2)
{
  IsResponseReceived = 'Yes';
}
```

In the above code my alert gives me 'No' everytime. I want to write someline inbetween alert and webservice call that should let me wait until I get response.

Am I Clear now?

Comment: Also, could you be more specific on what you mean by wait until response from webservice received?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider using pure JavaScript (pretty unusual these days), consider this code

```
var strURL = "localhost/services/foobar.svc";
var xmlHttpReq = false;
var self = this;
// Mozilla/Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
self.xmlHttpReq.open('GET', strURL, true);
self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
        // do whatever you want to do when your service responded
        // you may get the response content using self.xmlHttpReq.responseText
    }
}
self.xmlHttpReq.send();
```

If you consider using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) (this one of the popular JavaScript framework around), its easy:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "localhost/services/foobar.svc",
  success: function(data){
    // this is fired on successful response
    // you will have response content in data parameter
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to wait my javascript code until response comes from webservice, as we know that it runs asynchronously and does not wait for response , rather it calls the method reference passed as parameter. my problem is I cannot execute code at second line until I get response.

Comment: Can you please describe, what do you mean by **wait**?

Comment: your question setting is wrong. You cant suspend/sleep a thread in c#/java. Anything you want to do after you get response from service is write codes in `SuccessResponseReceiver`

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlHttpRequest (Ajax) and handle the response in your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the service synchronously then you can call the webservice from code behind as well. By default the main thread would wait till you receive response from service.

Comment: In my code, postback to server will cause lotd of viewstate to load and unload, so I can't do it from server side